# Upgraded Azure Function cannot test from the portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We had a Azure Function with Timer Trigger which was develop using function version 3.0 and .NET 3.1. This function is running on Windows App Service Plan on Azure. So, I have upgraded it to function version 4.0 and .NET 6.0 using below steps:

**Upgrade your local project**
The following changes are required in the .csproj XML project file:

1. Change the value of PropertyGroup.TargetFramework to net6.0.
2. Change the value of PropertyGroup.AzureFunctionsVersion to v4.
3. Replace the existing ItemGroup.PackageReference list with the following ItemGroup:
   Image
   After you make these changes, your updated project should look like the following example:
   Image
4. Upgrade the local.settings.json file
   Image
5. Run the function app locally and verify the functionality.

**Upgrade your function app in Azure**

1. Run below command to set the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION application setting to ~4 on your function app in Azure.

   az functionapp config appsettings set --settings FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=~4 -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -n <APP_NAME>
2. Change the .NET version of the function app. If you're function app is hosted on Windows, run below command.

   az functionapp config set --net-framework-version v6.0 -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -n <APP_NAME>

However, I cannot test or see the function.json file from Azure Portal.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the reason for the issue by running "**Diagnose and solve problems**" from Azure portal.

The issue was related to the function name. My function name length was more than 32 characters long. By default, the Host ID is auto-generated from the Function App name, by taking the first 32 characters. If you have multiple Function Apps sharing a single storage account and they're each using the same Host ID (generated or explicit), that can result in a Host ID collision. For example, if you have multiple apps with names longer than 32 characters their computed IDs may be the same. Consider two Function Apps with names **myfunctionappwithareallylongname-eastus-production** and

**myfunctionappwithareallylongname-westus-production**

that are sharing the same storage account. The first 32 characters of these names are the same, resulting in the same Host ID **myfunctionappwithareallylongname** being generated for each(Please refer https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Host-IDs#host-id-collisions for more information).

So, to solve the issue, I just rename the function name on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

***I have taken the .NET 3.1 Azure Function Project with Timer Trigger in the VS 2022 IDE:***

[image]

Published the .NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions Project to Azure Function App in the Azure Portal and then changed the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to 4 using Azure CLI Command by following this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc,azure-cli,windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#upgrade-your-function-app-in-azure):

[image]

[image]

***Running locally after migration to V4-.NET 6**:*

[image]

Then, deployed the migrated project to the Azure Function App and tested as shown below:

[image]